# Commit inside postgressql11 procedure throwing error when call from sqlalchemy engine

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, postgresql-11

Postgres Version : 11

Procedure code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.prc_insert_proc(table_name character varying)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $procedure$ declare StartTime timestamptz;

EndTime timestamptz;

Delta double precision;
err_context text;
tab_partition RECORD;
v_tab_partition varchar;
begin

for tab_partition in (SELECT
    child.relname       AS child
FROM pg_inherits
    JOIN pg_class parent            ON pg_inherits.inhparent = parent.oid
    JOIN pg_class child             ON pg_inherits.inhrelid   = child.oid
    JOIN pg_namespace nmsp_parent   ON nmsp_parent.oid  = parent.relnamespace
    JOIN pg_namespace nmsp_child    ON nmsp_child.oid   = child.relnamespace
WHERE parent.relname=table_name) loop
v_tab_partition = tab_partition.child;
begin
execute 'insert
    into
        test_tab (id,
    report_date,
        effective_asof_date,
        effective_until_date,
        active_flag) select id,
      to_date(report_date,''YYMMDD'') report_date,
            now(),
            ''31-Dec-2200'',
            ''Y''
        from '||
            tab_partition.child ||'  on
            conflict (id) do update set report_date=excluded.report_date;';
commit;
end;

end loop;



exception
    when others then
        GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS err_context = PG_EXCEPTION_CONTEXT;
        RAISE INFO 'Error Name:%',SQLERRM;
        RAISE INFO 'Error State:%', SQLSTATE;
        RAISE INFO 'Error Context:%', err_context;

end;

$procedure$;
```

I am calling above procedure by creating sqlalchemy engine and then calling this procedure.

```
def load_test(session, table, log):  # pragma: no cover
    try:
        sql = "call prc_insert_proc('" + \
            table + "');"
        session.execute(text(sql).execution_options(autocommit=False))
        session.commit()
    except ErrorBase as e:
        log.error(f"{str(e)}")
        raise
```

It is throwing up following error. Session was created using sessionmaker and create_engine.

```
engine = create_engine(config.connection_string, echo=False)
Session = sessionmaker()
Session.configure(bind=engine)
session = Session()
```

> invalid transaction termination

I am pretty new to both sqlalchemy and PostgreSQL.Each partition of the table has about a million record and I want to commit after every insert. Other option would be get the list of partition in the python script and add partition name parameter in procedure. Loop through the procedure in python and commit after every call. However, when I read that in PostgreSQL 11 we can commit inside the  procedure than I thought of using that.